# Jsoup parsing stuck in inifinite loop

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to parse some web retrieved pages.
For some reasons Jsoup gets into an infinite loop when trying to parse the content at http://higherperspectives.com/keanu-reeves-life/

Here is the code used:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(searchResult.get("link"))
            .timeout(500).followRedirects(false).validateTLSCertificates(false)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36")
            .maxBodySize(0).get();

Elements classElements = document.select("*:containsOwn(${owlSearchTerm.get("class")})");
Elements relationElements = document.select("*:containsOwn(${owlSearchTerm.get("relation")})");
Elements individualElements = document.select("*:containsOwn(${owlSearchTerm.get("individual")})");
```

The connect method never ends. The connection is successfully established but I guess the problem appears when Jsoup creates the Document object.

Is there a way to skip a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand why you are using the maxBodySize(0) option.
I 've tried it without it and it runs fine and returns the Document.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using Jsoup in a loop to retrieve multiple web pages and extract some HTML tags of interest. Jsoup gets stuck at some of them. The most frequent is the one mentioned in my answer. Could this be a memory problem? I removed maxBodySize option but the problem persists.

Comment: if all web pages are just sub directories of the main one then i could only assume that the website cuts you off cause it realises you are a robot. if not i can't really guess anything else. Don't u get any Errors when the retrieve fails?
Is it possible tha the link you are getting from the search result ist the same over and over again and u r just pasing the same page?

Comment: I am using Google custom search API to retrieve first N results for a search term. Then, for each result, I use Jsoup to retrieve some tags of interest from that URL. I had lots of tests using the same search term in the last period of time so it is very likely that I accessed the same page multiple times. If the website cuts me off I guess Jsoup should throw some errors but I get none. It is simply stuck at Jsoup.connect without reaching the next line.

Comment: then my only suggestion would be to add the source code of jsoup in your workspace (if you already havent) and debug through your this specific attempt to retrieve the page in order to get a glimpse of where the thing stucks. That could hopefully help you get the root of the problem

Comment: Ok. I will give it a try and I will come back with the results. Thanks!